# Trace of 4 gamma matrices

Tags: momentum, dirac-matrices, trace

Can anyone help me understand how do i execute this trace?

$$ Tr(\gamma_\mu(\gamma^\rho P_{1_\rho})\gamma_\nu (\gamma^\sigma K_{1_\sigma}))  $$

I know the rule when we have 4 gammas inside the trace, but I don't know how to execute that rule, because here we have also the P and K vectors.

Comment: What do you mean by the subscripts $1_\rho$ and $1_\sigma$? Or are the vectors $P_1$ and $K_1$ instead of $P$ and $K$?

Comment: because i am studying electron/muon scattering. The 1 indices represent  the momentum of the particles before the collision. P_1 is the momentum of the electron before the collision and K_1 that of the muon before. You can easily just leave them

Comment: When you have everything written out and no dirac slashes, you can move the momenta outside the trace while performing the trace, for example $\mathrm{Tr}(\gamma_{\mu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma_{\nu}\gamma^{\sigma})P_{1_{\rho}}K_{1_{\sigma}}$. As for the value of the trace, that is one of the proofs on wikipedia about the gamma matrices themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The $P$ and $K$ momentum vectors commute with the gamma matrices, $$Tr(\gamma_\mu\gamma^\rho\gamma_\nu\gamma^\sigma P_\rho K_\sigma)$$ and the trace is always meant to be for the matrices only*
$$Tr(\gamma_\mu\gamma^\rho\gamma_\nu\gamma^\sigma) P_\rho K_\sigma$$

**even though is true that you can't calculate the trace of a vector, as a comment pointed out these aren't vector but vector components, so numbers. But still they don't count towards the trace, because they don't have spinorial matix indices*

Comment: There is not even a problem with traces of vectors since in that expression the $P_\rho$ and $K_\sigma$ are only numbers.